# Python Pandas Groupby Count Error

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have a list with columns "school" and "scores1" and "scores2", i'm trying to groupby in order to get unique school record and do a count for scores1 greater than or equal to 70 and count for scores2 greater than or equal to 70. can anyone help me? this is the error i'm getting:

[image]

my sample list:
[image]

Comment: Please do not post images on stack-overflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sum boolean values

```
df.set_index('school').ge(70).sum(level=0)

                      reading_score  reading_score2
school                                             
Rosemead High School            2.0             1.0
SDDE High School                1.0             1.0
Arcadia High School             1.0             2.0
```

---

### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Rosemead High School', 66, 79],
    ['Rosemead High School', 94, 61],
    ['Rosemead High School', 90, 60],
    ['SDDE High School', 67, 58],
    ['SDDE High School', 97, 84],
    ['Arcadia High School', 70, 80],
    ['Arcadia High School', 50, 55],
    ['Arcadia High School', 65, 77],    
], columns=['school', 'reading_score', 'reading_score2'])
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. Btw, shouldn't we use `df.ge` for greater and equal than?

Answer (score 3):

I think need filter first:

```
df1 = (student_df > 70).groupby(student_df['school'])['reading_score', 'reading_score2'].sum()
```